# Why can't i reference to a method/property? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Please take a look at the 2 photos i attached, i wish to call the methods from one project to another. Both projects are in the same solution. I have already made the reference to the project containing the method in the project i want to call the method.

http://postimg.org/image/m42dlc28r/

http://postimg.org/image/w03gkz80r/

Comment: Why don't you post source code? These images are worthless.

Comment: Please take a moment to review this carefully: [Ask]

Comment: Which part of the source code? The project is humongous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main project, go to 
Project -> Add Reference
 In that window, click browse and find the compiled version of your other project (Probably in the Release or Debug folder)

In your main projects window add this to the very top of your code (even above your class declaration)

```
Imports SecondProjectRootNamespace
```

That should give you enough information on how to do what your trying to do, but if anything was unclear, I am going to need all the details to provide a more precise answer.

Also, make sure your methods/functions are NOT declared as private.

Private = Method is only visible from within the same class
Friend = Method is only visible from any class within the same assembly (same .exe or .dll or etc)
Public = Method has no access restrictions

There are a few others but those are the basics

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the dll file of the method that you want, then add it as reference in the properties of your application